# Load url in desktop view in android studio

Tags: android

How to create an android app that  load an webpage in desktop view format. And also rest all of the pages that load in webview format that page also must be in desktop view.

Comment: But it is not working . Can you send the overall oncreate code?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can do it by setting custom user agent like bellow

```
String userAgentCustom= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgentCustom);
```

Comment: Thanks  Dhaval solanki